# Virtual Ubuntu VM on Google Cloud can't connect via nodejs, external ip

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, npm, google-cloud-platform

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var path = require('path');

var app = express();

app.listen(3000, function(){
        console.log('Server up on Port 3000');
});
```

*I did search and try other solutions here but I still can't figure it out*

I have ubuntu on a google cloud compute engine (VM) and i'm trying to access it from the internet on my laptop. I'm using nodejs/ npm/ express.

The above is my index.js file (very basic) and when I start that using the following on the VM

```
nodejs index.js
```

*35.188.226.109 is the external ip for the VM*

When navigating in chrome to http://35.188.226.109:3000/ it says the site can't be reached.

What am I missing?

Comment: You have to open port from firewalls. Check your default network and add a new firewall rule to allow port tcp:3000 from all ips and it should work fine.

Comment: I added a rule on my gateway but, there is no difference. Do you mean on google cloud change a firewall?

Comment: Yes. Go to https://console.cloud.google.com/networking/firewalls/list and add a new firewall rule to allow traffic to your instance.

Comment: Ok got it, thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

When you launch a VM in the GCP, it's connected with a default network. That default network is in the most secure settings and will have firewall based port blocking for all the port except SSH and few others.

In order to allow external applications to communicate with your VM you have to enable access to your machine by enabling the port from the firewall.

Firewall settings can be found [here](https://console.cloud.google.com/networking/firewalls/list).

In your case, add a new firewall rule to allow port 3000 from all the IPs. Remember that this is not the best practice. Use port forwarding, proxies etc.